# How can I add a button in Tamper monkey script to redirect to another website?

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink, tampermonkey, userscripts

I need a custom userscript for tampermonkey which has a button that can redirect to another website via a new Tab?

```
/  document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
                            //    location.href = "https:website";
```

Comment: See the `target` parameter of the [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method and [how to attach an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#event_listener_with_an_arrow_function) to an element at MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of such a script.

At the top, in the `//==UserScript==` section, you change the `//@match` line to be the site you want the button to appear on. *When you navigate to that site, the button will be there.*

In the setTimeout, inside the event listener, you change the URL for the site you want the button to open up.

You need the setTimeout function because this userscript injects a button onto the page and then adds an event listener to the button. You must allow some time (500ms in this example) for the button to exist on the page before attempting to add the event listener to it. That is, the button must actually exist before you can attach an event listener to it.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Inject new button to navigate to new site
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://updat.cc
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

    $('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', init_css() );

    setTimeout(() => {
        //setTimeout needed to allow a few ms for the new Btn to be injected onto page
        $('#mybutt').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.open('https://rumble.com/user/vivafrei');
        });
    },500);
})();
function init_css(){
    return `
    <button id="mybutt">GoTo NewPage</button>
    <style>
        #mybutt{position:absolute;top:90px;left:45%;height:30px;width:120px;}
        #mybutt{background:#0073ea;color:white;padding-top:5px;text-align:center;}
        #mybutt{z-index:99999;}
    </style>
    `;
}
```